# Issue with binding datatable to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am calling the server and returning a datatable of results but when I try to bind to the gridview, it is throwing an error about not being able to find a field or property on the data source.  I'm newer to gridviews and .NET controls so any help would be appreciated.

**The GridView**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_Search" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gv_Search_Sorting">
   <Columns>
      <asp:HyperLinkField NavigateUrl="#" Text="View"/>
      <asp:BoundField SortExpression="Hdefendant_name" HeaderText="Name" DataField="Hdefendant_name"/>
      <asp:BoundField  SortExpression="Hdefendant_location" HeaderText="Location" DataField="Hdefendant_location"/>
      <asp:BoundField  SortExpression="Hdate" HeaderText="Date Entered" DataField="Hdate"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**The Code-Behind for Gridview page**
(resultsList is a DataTable type)

```
var resultsList = defendantRepository.Search(start, end, name, location);

if (Defendant.hasRecords)
{
    ViewState["PreliminaryInjunctions"] = resultsList.Columns;
    gv_Search.DataSource = resultsList.Columns;
    gv_Search.DataBind();
}
```

**The Search** (populates a DataTable and returns it to the variable resultsList from above)
dv is a DefaultView and
ds is a DataSet

```
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
  da.SelectCommand = cmd;
  da.Fill(ds, "PreliminaryInjunctions");
}
dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

dt = dv.ToTable();
return dt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is I believe that you are binding the GridView to the Data Table's `Columns` property:

```
gv_Search.DataSource = resultsList.Columns;
gv_Search.DataBind();
```

That property is of type [`DataColumnCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which does not contain names matching those defined in the `BoundField` elements, and hence the error.

Instead bind to the DataTable itself:

```
gv_Search.DataSource = resultsList;
gv_Search.DataBind();
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  I'm not sure why I tried binding to columns either now that I think about it..Will accept your answer in 2 minutes when S.O. will allow me